# How to show buffernames in airline when several tabs are open?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

I am using vim in a terminal and the airline plugin.

When I open more than one tab, airline only shows tabs name and not buffer name anymore. Is there a way to show the name of the buffers in the current tab?

Comment: What are related buffers ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I have two tabs and each tab with buffers and when I switch from one tab to another I want to see the list of buffers related with that tab at top like shows when not using tabs (just buffers)

Comment: @carlitux: According to [this issue](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues/639) it seems that this feature isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try [vim bufferline](https://github.com/bling/vim-bufferline).

Airline shows open buffers on the top bar only when you don't have any tabs. When you open another tab there are only tab names on that bar. With `bufferline` you can see all open buffers on the bottom bar (or at least some of them, if you have many buffers opened at once and there's not enough space on screen), regardless of the tab you are currently in.

I recommend reading about the [differences between tabs and buffers](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/), specifically, why buffers are preferred way of working with vim.

Comment: thanks I already read it... I have two proyects that needs open so I am using tabs and on each tab the file related withe the project.